# CSS styling precedence when using React and CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I have a css module which apply styling to an existing component. The css module works fine but the styling was always overwritten by the default style of component.

Supposed I have this markup.

```
 <Header className={styles.header}>
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-between">
        <Col>
          <Link to="/">
            <Title className={styles.brand}>Shiritori</Title>
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
 </Header>
```

Then uses the styles declare in the css module:

```
.header {
  background: rgb(75, 191, 107);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;

  > div {
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

I expect that the `background` css property of the default style will be overwritten but instead the styles in my css module was canceled out.

Actual result:

```
.ant-layout-header {
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    line-height: 64px;
    background: #001529;
}
.ant-layout-header, .ant-layout-footer {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.ant-layout, .ant-layout * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.App_header__37gyT {
    background: #4bbf6b; <- this property was overwritten by the .ant-layout-header background property
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

I also consider the order of css/scss import but same result.

```
import "../../../node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css";
import styles from "./App.module.scss";
```

Is there a way to overwrite existing style of a component. I use antd for the UI toolkit and components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to replicate your issue. Seems to be working fine:

[image: Edit Ant-Design CSS Specifity]

**That said, when dealing with CSS specificity, you can do one of several things:**

1. Overwrite a child class style from a parent class style.
2. Use the `id` property: `<Header id="header-id">Header</Header>` (then use the `#` to refer to header: `#header-id { ... }`)
3. Overwrite the `.ant-layout` class name within a separate CSS/SCSS file.
4. Add an `!important` declaration after the style property, for example: `background: pink !important;`

That said, I'd avoid importing the entire CSS library and instead use the [babel plugin](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce#Use-modularized-antd) to import only what's needed.

Comment: It's weird, the sandbox is the same with mine but produces different results. I'll override the default css.
Offtopic, how did you extract each class from the module. Got an error when extract classes in typescript.

Comment: If you can't destruct class names, the it sounds like you might not be using css modules, but `global` modules instead. Are you using a custom webpack configuration? If so, does it handle `local` modules? If you're using the `create-react-app`, then local modules must be `.module.(s)css`, otherwise they're interpreted as global (S)CSS. If you're not using the CRA, then you have to manually configure webpack to handle local and global modules.

Comment: I'm using CRA and destructure works but lints an error due to typescript. anyways thanks for the response.